# How do cleaning supplies, such as hand sanitizer or Clorox wipes, kill viruses?

Tags: virus, sanitation, hand-sanitizers

I know that viruses are not living or nonliving things, and thus they cannot be "killed." I was wondering how the viruses would no longer be able to infect people after the application of things like hand sanitizer.

Comment: answered here https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21744/does-bleach-have-to-be-diluted-to-be-more-effective-to-kill-virus/21746#21746

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?